# Grouping words together in array literal `%w`

Tags: arrays, ruby, literals

Is there any way to combine more than one word together in `%w(foo bar)` notation to get the resulting array as follows?

```
%w(foo bar foo or bar foo and bar) # => ["foo", "bar", "foo or bar", "foo and bar"]
```

Comment: Don't you think that simply writing `["foo", "bar", "foo or bar", "foo and bar"]` is way simpler than trying to figure out any tricks (if any)? Why insist on `%w`?

Comment: What about `(foo or bar or bat)` or `(for or bar and bat)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can excape a whitespace with `\`:

```
%w(foo bar foo\ or\ bar foo\ and\ bar)
#=> ["foo", "bar", "foo or bar", "foo and bar"]
```

But I am not sure if this improves readability...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using `\` as the space character:

```
%w(foo bar foo\ or\ bar foo\ and\ bar) => ["foo", "bar", "foo or bar", "foo and bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using `%w` notation, but with a similar spirit, using `|` instead of space for a delimiter:

```
"foo|bar|foo or bar|foo and bar".split("|")
```